# javafx choice box is empty on setValue()

Tags: java, javafx

In my project I have a table. When the user double clicks on the row, an editing dialog opens. On the opening this dialog I set values to fields, few of which are ChoiceBoxes. The type of ChoiceBox's field is a custom object, not a string.

The code that creates the [ChoiceBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html#setValue(T)) follows:

```
trade_point.setConverter(new TradePointConverter());
trade_point.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(tradePointsService.getTradePoints()));
TradePoint currentTradePoint = tradePointsService.getTradePoint(typeOfPriceByTradePoint.getTradePoint()); 
trade_point.setValue(currentTradePoint);
```

Where trade_point is a choice box of TradePoint type. currentTradePoint is not null, when I look at trade_point's value equals currentTradePoint's value but in the dialog I see no value. Items are set correctly. in other case with same choice box filling everything is correct and here is not.

**UPD:** TradePointConverter class:

```
    class TradePointConverter extends StringConverter<TradePoint>{
        public TradePoint fromString(String name){
            try {
                List<TradePoint> tradePoints = tradePointsService.getTradePoints();

                for (TradePoint tradePoint1: tradePoints){
                    if (tradePoint1.getName().equals(name)){
                        return tradePoint1;
                    }
                }
            }catch (SQLException e){

            }
            return null;
        }
        public String toString(TradePoint tradePoint1){
            return tradePoint1.getName();
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if this converter is correct as far as converting from string by name is totally incorrect. I do not understand how to make it correctly visible to the user (to see the name of an object) and how to store its id to get the definite object at the same time. I can convert to string by getting an id but in this case user won't understand which object to choose.

trade_point is a ChoiceBox:

```
private ChoiceBox<TradePoint> trade_point = new ChoiceBox<TradePoint>();
```

Comment: I think it is closely related with converter. Show its code. And you sure that it is choicebox and not combobox?

Comment: @UlukBiy look at the update

Comment: @silverest you suggest me answer for the ComboBox when I speak about ChoiceBox